# Number of users to a webpage

Tags: scalability, ms-access

I have a webpage that reads data from an Access file (Microsoft Access file) on my website. How many users can visit that page at the same time?

Would the page crash at some time if too many users tried to visit that page at the same time? Is it better to use a PHP file that reads data from a text file or its just the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my website was hosted on [Domain.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain.com). *Domain.com* say that I have unlimited bandwidth frequency. But in reality I don't.

My website was crashing, because it was hosted with thousands of websites on the same server. So the bandwidth is limited even though it says unlimited. My only solution was to host my website on a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server). Basically hosting my website on a server by itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are many variables that influence how many people can simultaneousness use your website (loosely known as scalability), including your database, hardware, network, caching and more.  And yes, at some point your performance will degrade if more and more users access the page.

It would be really hard to say from the information you provided how scalable your website is.  PHP could be faster but not necessarily.  Always be skeptical about technologies that promise superior performance.

For the moment your best option is to try and estimate how many concurrent users you are expecting and then use a load testing tool like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) or [others](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) to assess if you're website will stand up to the load.

Comment: Leonm, Does access file have some kinda limit to be opened simultaneousness ? I mean could thousand of users open it at the same time?

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing.  It'll depend on how much data you have, the queries executed for each user, whether you cache any data, and other factors.  With so many variables at play it is almost impossible to tell without measuring.